# What steps are involved when adding Globalize to my Rails Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, globalize

I have a rails project that needs to be multi-lingual. I ran into a few issues while enabling globalize for my rails project.

I was wondering if there is a thorough checklist / recipe for enabling internationalisation for a rails app.

Please note that I use ActiveAdmin which needs to be part of this as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Installation

Set the locales you wish to support in your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.i18n.available_locales = [:de, :en]
```

Add migrations like described in the [Globalize Readme](https://github.com/globalize/globalize)

Make sure to remove `NOT NULL` constraints on columns that you're translating since they will be migrated over to the new translations table:

```
change_column :categories, :title, :string, null: true
```

#### Setting the locale

Detect the language based on the HTTP Accept Language Header:

`application_controller.rb`

```
# ...
def set_locale
  I18n.locale = extract_locale
end

def extract_locale
  headers = request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'] || 'de'
  case headers.scan(/^[a-z]{2}/).first
    when 'en'
      'en'
    else
      'de'
  end
end
```

#### Empty `''` translations

Globalize provides a fallback mechanism for missing translations. I was a bit surprised that some values didn't have a fallback on my front end. This was caused by blank values. To fix this I had to add the option `fallbacks_for_empty_translations: true` for the `translates` method call:

```
translates :title, :description, fallbacks_for_empty_translations: true
```

**Note**: This option can also used for the `active_admin_translates` method call.

### ActiveRecord

#### Scopes and Queries

Scopes that use the translated fields have to be changed as well:

```
default_scope -> { order :title }
```

becomes:

```
default_scope -> { order('category_translations.title').includes(:translations) }
```

### Active Admin

#### Setup

There is a gem that supports Globalize as well as ActiveAdmin:

```
# For Rails 4 use the master branch from github
gem "activeadmin-globalize", github: 'stefanoverna/activeadmin-globalize', branch: 'master'
```

#### Filters

Filters for translated attributes will no longer work by default:

```
filter :title
```

Will have to be changed to:

```
# as: :string is required otherwise the filter won't be shown
filter :translations_name, as: :string
```

#### Sorting

While the following works for translated columns:

```
# Admin: Categories.rb
index do
  column :title
end
```

As soon as we want to sort, there is an error, because the column `title` is not in the DB.

**Update** I only had this on certain models and it is not clear to me when this fails. So for some models I had to disable sorting:

```
column :title, sortable: false
```

Comment: Was trying to find this code `filter :translations_name, as: :string` for a long time! My filters with translations did not work, now its perfect! Any solution for sortable yet? Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you can sort by translation: http://blog.sed.hu/2014/07/01/ruby-on-rails-active-admin-ransack-and-globalize-part-1/

Comment: @micred The link for sorting by translation is dead, anyone know how to do it?